# return undefined when i call JSON array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am trying to create a JSON array inside another JSON array. 
I think I did it right, but when I call the second array it returns undefined.

JSON file :

```
var files = [
    {"Files" : [
        {"file1" : "file1"},
        {"file2" : "file2"},
        {"file3" : "file3"}
    ]},

    {"Texts" : [
        {"file4" : "file4"},
        {"file5" : "file5"},
        {"file6" : "file6"}
    ]}
];
```

When I trying this command it works -

```
console.log(files[0]); // Works, returns the array
```

But when I trying this command it not working -

```
console.log(files[0][1]); // Not working, return undefined
```

I expect that this will return file2.

What I did wrong ?

EDIT :
The script gets JSON file like that from the server, and the script need to loop through the JSON. So think about the names ( Files, Texts, file1, file2 etc.. ) as unknown..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
console.log(files[0]["Files"])  // will return array with file 1-3
console.log(files[0]["Texts"])  // will return array with file 4-6
```

or

```
console.log(files[0].Files)  // will return array with file 1-3
console.log(files[0].Texts)  // will return array with file 4-6
```

in you example `files[0][1]` work for json like this

```
var files = [
    [
        {"file1" : "file1"},
        {"file2" : "file2"},
        {"file3" : "file3"}
    ],
    [
        {"file4" : "file4"},
        {"file5" : "file5"},
        {"file6" : "file6"}
    ]
];
```

EDIT
in this case you can use next `for-loop`

```
for (var key in files[0])
{
   files[0][key] // here key is "Files", this will return files 1-3       
}​
```

Comment: The script gets JSON file like that from the server, and the script need to loop through the JSON. So think about the names as unknown..

Answer (score 5):

This:

```
console.log(files[0]);
```

does **not** log an **array**, it's the object that's the first element of the array. To get to the inner array, you have to get at the "Files" attribute of that object:

```
console.log(files[0].Files[1]);
```

What that will log is not just the string "file2", but the entire object, `{ file2: "file2" }`. In JavaScript, object properties with string property names cannot be accessed by numeric index. That is, in the object:

```
{ "foo": "hello world" }
```

there simply is no `[0]` property.  Arrays in JavaScript are also objects and can have string-named properties, but they're separate from the collection of numerically-indexed properties.

Answer (score 2):

The arrays are inside of the Files property:

```
console.log(files[0].Files[0]);
console.log(files[0].Files[1]);
```